# mix 2 mysql date columns to one and order by

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table "USER" in MySQL , some columns are "ID","Name","Birth" and "Death"... Birth and Death save date values.

I want to display both Birth and Death and then order by date ASC.

Here is an example from what I have and what I need..

```
column Birth:
1-2-99
2-2-99

column Death:
1-1-99
2-3-99

desired result from a query:
1-1-99 (from death col)
1-2-99 (from Birth col)
2-2-99 (from Birth col)
2-3-99 (from death col)
```

The example is displayed as (DD,MM,YY)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `UNION` or `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT `date`
FROM
(
    SELECT death AS `date` FROM tablename
    UNION ALL
    SELECT birth           FROM tablename
) AS t
ORDER BY `date`;
```

Comment: Gamal, seems it works thanks, but now i cant figure how to show the rest of the columns like name etc.. something like 'select *, date from users ,(select death as date from tablename'

Comment: @Musikdoktor - You have to select them inside the subquery: `SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT name, foo, bar, death AS date FROM tablename
    UNION ALL
    SELECT name, foo, bar, birth   FROM tablename
) AS t
ORDER BY date;`

Comment: Excellent my Friend, thanks you very much.. Happy new year!

Comment: @Musikdoktor - You're welcome any time :) Happy new year you too :)